# Unable to perform like queries with sugar db

Tags: android, sugarorm

Im using the following code to fetch data from sqlite using Sugar Db

```
  String query = "SELECT * FROM trending where  like ( '%' ||" + existence + "|| '%' , category)";
    List<Trending> trendings = Trending.findWithQuery(Trending.class, query);
```

But it produces the following error,

```
 no such column: Existence (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM trending where  like ( '%' ||Existence|| '%' , category)
```

How can I be able to perform LIKE queries with Sugar Db

Comment: Your problem has more to do with SQL than Sugar; that's not how to build a query string using LIKE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with sugar DB. You're producing bad SQL. The query should be

```
... WHERE foo LIKE '%Existence%'
```

You're missing the `foo` field name, and since you're building a text string to insert your actual query value, you do NOT need to have SQL concatenation at as well.

Try:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM trending where category like '%" + existence + "%'"
```

Comment: category is the field name

Comment: I want ton grab list of all rows where the value of category is existence